# fetching products of current user_id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have function to fetch the products from `ci_products` table 
the code is as follows

```
function get_product_selections($product_ids = array())
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ci_products');
    $this->db->where_in('product_id', $product_ids);

    $products = $this->db->get();
    return $products;
}
```

now I want to fetch from where `user_id` is `current user_id`
I have tried few things but not working 
what I have tried`

```
function get_product_selections($product_ids = array())
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ci_products');
    $this->db->where_in('product_id', $product_ids);
      $this->db->where('user_id',$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    $products = $this->db->get();
    return $products;
}
```

Comment: do you want to search `product_id` based on `user_id` in  `ci_products` table?

Comment: Are you getting any error. What you were getting with this query. Can you post your working query

Comment: not any error it shows all the products from the ci_products table i wanted to show the products only where user_id is current user_id

Comment: try to `echo $this->db->last_query();` and check that you were getting the query perfectly or any error

Answer (score 1):

```
$data = $this->db->get_where('product_ids',$product_ids);
$this->db->where_in('product_ids',$data);
$this->db->where('user_id',$this->session->userdata('user_id'));
$query =  $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Comment: i hope may be usefull for you

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

In your first code:

```
function get_product_selections($product_ids)
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ci_products');
    $this->db->where('product_id', $product_ids);

    $products = $this->db->get();
    return $products->result_array();
}
```

what do you mean when you put array() in the parameter? you want to retrieve an array() of products?

```
function get_product_selections()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ci_products');
    $this->db->where('user_id',$this->session->userdata('user_id')); // the user who is currently login
    $products = $this->db->get();

    return $products->result_array(); // return the results
}
```

Comment: if you only want to query one row  you can also use first_row('array') instead of result_array(). If you want to view ,,if there products you can use this one , vardump($products);  if you have clarifications don't hesitate to ask. ^_^

Comment: Thanx Xammeil what all i want is to get the product id to get but i want to show the product where user_id is of current user

Comment: so you mean you just want to retrieve the product  of the current user? is it what you mean?

Comment: what is the table name of  user_id ? did you join the ci_products and the table for users?